# Setting up a static Ip on Ubuntu 16 server inside a VMWare Workstation

Tags: networking, server, dns, vmware, dhcp

I would like to set up a static IP for my server, however I seem to have made a mistake.

My current `/etc/network/interface` file is set to the following

```
auto ens33 
iface ens33 inet static
address 192.168.150.130
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.150.2
dns-nameserver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

After the restart the server has no internet connection.
[DHCP settings image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxfQq.png)

Comment: Is `192.168.150.0/24` the range of your host network? if so, have you configured the VM in bridged mode?

Comment: I believe it is *dns-nameservers*; please change it and restart the interface: `sudo ifdown ens33 && sudo ifup -v ens33` Look for errors, warnings or other clues.

Comment: It does seem that there are some errors.
I ran the ens33 command and got:
>Listening on LPF/ens33/00:0c:29.... 
>Sending on LPF/ens33/00:0c:29....
>Sending on Socket/failback
>DHCPRELEASE on ens33 to 192.168.150.254 port 67 (xid=0x67d19cf6)
>send_packet: Network is unreachable
>send_packet: please consult README.... 
>dhclient .c: 2474: Failed to send 300 byte long packet over fallback interface.

Comment: It is configured in NAT starting IP 192.168.150.129 ending ip 192.168.150.254 subnet mask: 255.255.255.0 subnet ip: 192.168.150.0 broadcast address: 192.168.150.255

Comment: NAT uses your host's internet connection. Ideally you'll need to refer to the NAT dhcp series that is set by VMWare (I'm not sure how that would work as I have not played with). And I'm also not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve there. Are you trying to access the guest VM from host VM or other devices on the network?

Comment: Yes, my intent is to be able to access the Ubuntu server throughout my network.

Answer (score 0):

Change your network adapter settings to

Custom -> VMnet8 (NAT)

on vm

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

and insert

```
auto ens33 
iface ens33 inet static
address 192.168.150.130
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.150.2
dns-nameservers 192.168.150.2
```

save it then

```
sudo service networking restart
```